# How to prevent a local file being synced with the remote repo?

Tags: git

I have a file that has authentication-related constants (e.g. client ID, client secret etc.), something like this:

```
public class AuthConstants {
    public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "Client secret here";
    ...
}
```

Now, I have committed and pushed this file with placeholder strings, so the client secrets are not shared with others. How do I keep it that way when I replace the placeholder strings with the actual ID, secret etc.?

To reiterate, I want

- the public repo to contain the placeholder version of this file
- the local repo to contain the actual version of this file
- to prevent accidentally revealing the actual version to the public repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the way to do this with `--assume-unchanged`:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filehere>
```

Comment: Well, the solution with --assume-unchanged isn't that convenient because it prevents one from easily change branches, you have to forcibly reset the working tree to its pristine state, effectively losing your changes and then switch branches.

Comment: @user3159253 It's fine for my purposes for now.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you shouldn't put this file under version control at all.

Use `.gitignore` (or sometimes better `.git/info/exclude`), **and** remove the file from **all** your previous commits using `git filter-branch`.

The problem with a "placeholder" is that git, once "acquired" a given file, will always check its content (and therefore changes) despite `.gitignore`/`.git/info/exclude`. So you always will have a chance to accidently submit a secret content.

If the placeholder is absolutely necessary (indeed, I would avoid it), then you could create a pre-commit hook which would break the process of making a commit, if you accidently staged the file for the commit.

Comment: I thought you could do something with `assume-unchanged` or something like that?

Comment: Likely you have a better solution than mine!

Comment: But still even with `--assume-unchanged` you'll have some problems when switching between branches etc. shortly speaking, git will abort the switch telling that there're some uncommitted changes